# IDE or Editor for Front-end development (JavaScript/HTML/CSS)?

Tags: editors, ide, javascript

These days APTANA seems to be the IDE of choice for Javascript developers although there is no package for Ubuntu or any other distribution.

How do I install Aptana on Ubuntu? Is it stable?

(if you can suggest alternatives they are welcome)

Comment: [Two questions closed. Why?](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/1071)

Comment: Because this posts looks like ads of some product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install Aptana on Ubuntu (try [those instructions](http://www.samclarke.com/2012/04/how-to-install-aptana-studio-3-on-ubuntu-12-04-lts-precise-pangolin/)). However, for a general-purpose IDE, I like [Geany](http://www.geany.org/).

> Geany is a text editor using the GTK2 toolkit with basic features of an integrated development environment. It was developed to provide a small and fast IDE, which has only a few dependencies from other packages. It supports many filetypes and has some nice features. For more details see About.

If you want to use vim or emacs, it might be worthwhile, too, to take a look around GitHub to see if other JS/HTML/CSS developers have shared their configuration files.

Comment: I'll try installing Aptana. I Checked Geany, it seems more back-end and native app oriented, it's look & feel is a bit.. outdated let's say..